# How to make a meta tag the first one in the <head> section?

Tags: jsf, internet-explorer-9, primefaces

I'm using JSF2, GlassFish 3.1, PrimeFaces 2.x.

I'm having strange rendering problems on IE9.  I'm supposed to be able to force IE9 to render as IE9 by inserting the following:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Enable IE9 Standards mode -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
...
```

But the thing is, it's not working because (I'm told) the meta tag MUST be the first tag in the  section.

When I do this in my XHTML file ...

```
<html ...>

<f:view contentType="text/html" locale="#{loginHandler.currentLocale}">

<h:head>
    <!-- Enable IE9 Standards mode -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

The resulting HTML looks like this, where JSF/PrimeFaces has inserted a bunch of "link" and "script" tags before my new meta tag.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/orcf-webui/javax.faces.resource/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/orcf-webui/javax.faces.resource/wijmo/wijmo.css.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/orcf-webui/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/orcf-webui/javax.faces.resource/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&amp;v=2.2"></script>
<!-- Enable IE9 Standards mode -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Is there any way to get my meta tag in the right place so it will work?  (Or an alternative way to make this IE9 problem go away?

Comment: According to the article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2012/02/29/using-x-ua-compatible-to-create-durable-enterprise-web-applications.aspx the meta tag must be at the begin of html head anyway, at least before any javascripts, so no matter of doctype, the problem is the order of head tags anyway.

Answer (score 29):

1. The meta tag must go **before** all PrimeFaces stuff:
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2012/02/29/using-x-ua-compatible-to-create-durable-enterprise-web-applications.aspx
2. HTTP Header and HTML HEAD are completly different things.
3. In PrimeFaces 3.0 the new **facet** was added to `h:head`:
   http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1433
   So the solution would be:

```xml
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
    </f:facet>
</h:head>
```

Comment: Your solution uses PrimeFaces 3.0, but the question was about PrimeFaces 2.x, where customizable resource ordering is not available.

Comment: add 2) - not exactly - for "X-UA-Compatible" (and some other headers) you can use either HTTP header or HTML "http-equiv" header (see "http-equiv")

Answer (score 15):

I think best solution is to create JSF PhaseListener which adds X-UA-Compatible header to HTTP response

```
public class UACompatibleHeaderPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        final FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
        response.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    }

}
```

and register it in faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.0">
  <lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>com.example.UACompatibleHeaderPhaseListener</phase-listener>
  </lifecycle>
</faces-config>
```

Another option would be to create servlet Filter and register it in web.xml.

Why is this needed?

1. Imagine your web application is deployed on a domain (or sub-domain) which is on IE compatibility list here: http://ie9cvlist.ie.microsoft.com/ie9CompatViewList.xml so you need to use X-UA-Compatible header to switch IE back to latest mode.
2. Imagine your web application is deployed on WebLogic server (which uses mojarra 2.0.4) so you cannot change JSF implementation.

[mojarra](/questions/tagged/mojarra)

Comment: And I think, It's a misunderstanding too. You are adding the HTTP header, which is something completly other as html header section.

Comment: But the <meta> tag *overrides* the http header,  so this won't work.

Comment: It worked for me. But it is strange that there are some places where it looks the same and there are where it looks quite different comparing to Chrome's and Firefox output. I will look into my css definitions in deep.

Comment: for "X-UA-Compatible" (and some other headers) you can use either HTTP header or HTML "http-equiv" header (see "http-equiv")

Answer (score 3):

You can create [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which adds header:

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=9
```

to response object.

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956197#5)

Comment: It's a significant difference between http header and html head section.

Comment: I know what are HTTP header and HTML head section. What is the difference between these approaches in the context of the question? I think that my solution is "alternative way to make this IE9 problem go away".

Comment: This explains the order of precedence: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128739/which-x-ua-compatible-takes-precedence-http-header-or-meta-tags

Comment: @DanubianSailor As long as there's only one X-UA-Compatible between the HTTP headers and the HTML head, either approach should work, right?

Answer (score 2):

Just to comment on your answer and previous comments:

HTTP Header and HTML Head are not completly different things (effectively) if you view page on IE8 as shown by [diagram here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2010/Mar/02_HowIE8DeterminesDocumentMode_3.png). If you set HTTP header, but not HTML Head, the directive from HTTP header is still taken into account.

I don't know how IE9 behaves, but I guess that in a similar way.

Comment: They are two completely different things, they just can (in limited cases) both be used to 'steer/direct' the browser to do things or not. And yes, one will override the other.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to switch from Mojarra to MyFaces. Looking at the source code of [MyFaces' HEAD renderer](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/myfaces/core/trunk/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/HtmlHeadRenderer.java?view=markup) - first gets rendered the content of the element and then other resources. Mojarra is doing this probably other way around. If you don't want to switch JSF implementations you can just implement your own HEAD element renderer.

However I would suggest just to find out why IE9 is not working without the *X-UA-Compatible* meta tag. It is supposed to make newer versions to behave like older versions.