# Which X-UA-Compatible takes precedence? Http-header or Meta-tags?

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers, meta-tags, x-ua-compatible

As the question states basically. If you have X-UA-Compatible in both your HTTP headers and a meta tag on your document, and they conflict, which one gets respected by IE?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**TL;DR: The meta tag wins**

I found the following (updated) flowchart <s>[here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2010/Jun/16_IEsCompatibilityFeaturesforSiteDevelopers_3.png)</s> (link is broken) and associated [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/16/ie-s-compatibility-features-for-site-developers.aspx) that provides an explanation of how IE9 determines document mode:

[image]

Comment: Its funny MS own documentation does not mention the Meta tag and simply states: "... the webpage is displayed in standards mode because it contains a <!DOCTYPE> directive that defines the page as an HTML5 document type." Yet it will fallinto quirks without the Meta tag. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: More info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2012/02/29/using-x-ua-compatible-to-create-durable-enterprise-web-applications.aspx