# Set Browser Mode and Document Mode IE in MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have developed an application in MVC3. It's working fine in Mozilla and Chrome. It also works properly in IE if I set the **Browser Mode and Document Mode to IE9**, but when my application loads in IE, it is by default set to **Browser Mode and Document Mode IE7** .

How can I set Browser Mode and Document Mode IE9 by default when my site is opened in IE?
I have also tried by putting this in `<head>` tag but there is no luck for me.
Please let me know how can I do this.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatiable" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you're having a typo in your meta tag. It should be `X-UA-Compatible`, not `X-UA-Compatiable`.

Also I prefer to send those flags as headers instead of meta tags. You can configure this in your web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

This way you don't need to worry about it in your HTML code. You can then override the behavior of single pages using the meta tag if necessary, as the meta tag takes precedence over the header. (See [Which X-UA-Compatible takes precedence? Http-header or Meta-tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128739/which-x-ua-compatible-takes-precedence-http-header-or-meta-tags))

Comment: thanks for reply, i have set these in my web.config i have one dot  if My IE Browser mode and Document Mode is set IE7 standers dy default. after loading my site it is not set Browser and Document Mode to IE9, is it possible with this tag? i want to set Browser and Document mode to IE9 whenever my site is load in IE.

Comment: @Shivkumar Do you set a proper DOCTYPE in your HTML document?