# InputDate popup not work IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, trinidad

I have a problem working with `<tr:inputDate>` and Internet Explorer 9. The calendar for picking the date it's not showing.  With Chrome/Firefox and previous versions of IE and IE compatibility mode works fine. I disabled the pop-up blocker but still not working. 
Any suggestion?

i'm working with:

- MyFaces v2.1.1
- Trinidad v2.0.0

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it by adding in the my implementation of the PhaseListener this code:

```
@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event){
FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();
final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse);
context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=EmulateIE8");
}
```

I got solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860779/how-to-make-a-meta-tag-the-first-one-in-the-head-section).

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others will be able to learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 2):

Either you used the wrong [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), or it's a bug in the HTML/CSS generated by `<tr:inputDate>`. As I've never used Trinidad, I can't confirm either of those possible causes.

After you've [reported](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD) this issue to the Trinidad guys, in the meanwhile your best bet is to force IE9 to render in IE8 compatibility mode by adding the following meta tag to the HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

Comment: It has to be the first tag in the HTML head.